# How can I use this React Hook to reflect 'logged in' status?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn how to effectively use React Hooks but am having an issue. I would like to reflect whether or not a user is "logged in" to the site using a JWT in local storage. When I first visit the page, the hook works as I intend, retrieving the user data. But if I click the "Log Out" button in the example below, the component does not update to reflect this, although it will if I refresh the page. How might I properly implement this hook to get it to update when logging in/out?

Custom hooks:

```
export const useUser = () => {
    const [token] = useToken();

    const getPayloadFromToken = token => {
        const encodedPayload = token.split('.')[1];
        return JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload))
    }

    const [user,setUser] = useState(() => {
        if(!token) return null;
        return getPayloadFromToken(token);
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!token) {
            setUser(null);
        } else {
            setUser(getPayloadFromToken(token));
        }
    }, [token]);

    return user;
}



export const useToken = () => {
    const [token, setTokenInternal] = useState(() => {
        return localStorage.getItem('token');
    });

    const setToken = newToken => {
        localStorage.setItem('token',newToken);
        setTokenInternal(newToken);
    }

    return [token, setToken];
}
```

Navigation Bar Component:

```
const NavigationBar = () => {
    const user = useUser();

    const logOut = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
    };


    return(
        <>
            <div>{user ? 'logged in' : 'logged out'}</div>
            <button onClick={logout}>Log Out</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: When you log out you'll need to update *some* state *somewhere* in order to trigger a React component rerender. Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] for what you are trying to accomplish? Are there any errors or is this just a logical issue where you need the UI/state to be more responsive to authentication changes?

Comment: I am able to solve the problem by putting the changes elsewhere in the state, but the part that confuses me is this: as I understand React Hooks, once the data in the hook changes, it should be reflected where the hook is implemented. Why doesn't changing the token (logging out) in useToken reflect changes in the useUser hook which depends on it?

Comment: Where do you change a token when logging out? AFAIK `logout` only removes the token from localStorage.

Comment: That is correct - so is there a way to update the setToken hook after this? If it were called again, it would see that the token has changed, and then the value of useUser would change. I suspect not, since hooks can only be called in the component body.

Comment: I think at a minimum you could expose out the `setToken` function directly via the `useUser` hook and when you call `logout` call `setToken(null)` (*or similar*) and this would be sufficient enough to trigger a render. Ideally though you'd have all this authentication "state" centrally located in a React context so the hooks all reference the same single state. I can provide an example if you like.

Comment: Hey, you helped me figure it out. Exposing the setToken functionality inside the useUser hook was the part I was missing - calling it in the useToken hook was not working. It is hard to understand what I was misunderstanding - I am new to React Hooks and the hooks shown are from a tutorial. But somehow I am on the right track now, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at a minimum you could expose out the `setToken` function directly via the `useUser` hook and when you call logout call `setToken(null)` (*or similar*) and this would be sufficient enough to trigger a render. Ideally though you'd have all this authentication "state" centrally located in a React context so the hooks all reference the same single state.

I suggest actually encapsulating the logout function within the `useUser` hook and exposing that out instead of directly exposing the `setToken` function. You want the hooks to maintain control over the state invariant and not rely on consumers to pass/set the correct state values.

Example:

```
export const useUser = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useToken();

  const getPayloadFromToken = token => {
    const encodedPayload = token.split('.')[1];
    return JSON.parse(atob(encodedPayload));
  }

  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
    if (!token) return null;
    return getPayloadFromToken(token);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) {
      setUser(null);
    } else {
      setUser(getPayloadFromToken(token));
    }
  }, [token]);

  const logout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    setToken(null);
  };

  return { user, logout };
}
```

...

```
export const useToken = () => {
  const [token, setTokenInternal] = useState(() => {
    // Initialize from localStorage
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Persist updated state to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(newToken));
  }, [token]);

  const setToken = newToken => {
    setTokenInternal(newToken);
  }

  return [token, setToken];
};
```

...

```
const NavigationBar = () => {
  const { logout, user } = useUser();

  return(
    <>
      <div>{user ? 'logged in' : 'logged out'}</div>
      <button onClick={logout}>Log Out</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. However, I have added a removeToken function to the useToken hook that deletes the token from local storage and sets the token variable to null. Exposing this as the logout function in the useUser hook is sufficient to update the user variable without having to also call setUser.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered something similar. A solution I found that worked for me was to save whether or not the user is logged in using Context. Effectively this would involve creating a wrapper around components in your app which need access to whether or not a user is logged in as an alternative to using local storage to save this sort of stuff.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply - In the actual version of this code (I stripped it down a bit for the example) the useUser and useToken hooks are actually provided through a Context component that is available to the entire application. It works when I want to access the data as the component loads, i.e. refreshing the page. I just need to figure out how to update the data afterwards.

Comment: Oh got you. Sorry I couldn't be of more help then. Good luck.

Comment: You're actually not far off from the correct answer, I suspect. I ended up using a solution pretty much exactly as you suggest; using the useUser hook in my code to retrieve the data and put it in Context. I believe the original way I wanted to do it is not possible, seeing as hooks can only be called in the body of a component and not activated later. Thanks again for the assistance.